# Change Configurable Product Name to Simple Name in Minicart & Cart

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

Over the past few days I have been trying to change the Product Name in the Minicart & Cart.

I have a configurable product with two child simple products.
When I select an option and add to cart, the configurable product title is shown and the option selected is under a "See Details" accordion.
How it looks by default:

[image: Default View]

What I would like is the child simple product name selected to populate the Minicart & Cart rather than the configurable title and for the "See Details" accordion to be hidden like such:

[image: Desired Outcome]

The child simple product title also needs to be linked to the configurable product page.
The child simple products are both set to not individually visible as they need to be, which strips the product link from the title by default. I need to override this so that the title in the minicart and cart shows the simple product title and that title links to the configurable page.

I've found bits of code (some here) that partially work but nothing very conclusive.
The best part working solution I had was [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/258267/70870). This shows the simple product title instead of the parent configurable but I need that extending to add the configurable product url link to the title.

What is the best way of going about this?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can follow this link for modify the product name.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315254/magento-2-change-productname-adding-to-cart